# React native init not working getting can't find variable _fbBatchedBridge IOS simulator

Tags: react-native

I posted this in the react native GitHub but was asked to post it here

I followed the instructions on the website to get a React native app up and running.

I get the following messages
Genymotion Andriod simulator Reference Error: can't find variable _fbBatchedBridge
IOS simulator Unable to execute JS call: _fbBatchedBridge is undefined
React Package Manager synchronization failed

React native version 0.18.0
React native cli 0.1.10
Node 4.2.4

Mac Os X Yosemite
XCode Version 7.2

In researching this many claim that the issue is with the network.  I opened a browser pointing at localhost:8081 and got a webpage with Cannot GET /

Currently, I am not getting any error message on the IOS simulator, just a blank white screen.  Android is still giving the same error message on both Genymotion and my local Android device.

There are no error messages on the Terminal or in XCode.

This is very frustrating to try to troubleshoot since I have no idea why it is not working or even where to start.

Comment: Are you running this from xcode?

Comment: Yes, both the IOS from Xcode (and then run simulator) and the android using the cli command.

Answer (score 1):

This error is because the script server is not running.

For Android version, in addition to execute 'react-native run-android' to build the app, you need to execute 'react-native start' to start the script server.

In XCode when you run the application the terminal should be started automatically, but it seems something is wrong in your case. Did you try to close the terminal window and start over?

==============================
when you first start the script server, the console should show

```
[18:07:15] <START> Building Dependency Graph
[18:07:15] <START> Crawling File System
[18:07:15] <START> Loading bundles layout
[18:07:15] <END>   Loading bundles layout (1ms)

React packager ready.
```

When your client connects to the server, the console should show

```
[18:07:25] <START> request:/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true
[18:07:25] <START> find dependencies
[18:08:01] <END>   Crawling File System (45771ms)
[18:08:01] <START> Building in-memory fs for JavaScript
[18:08:04] <END>   Building in-memory fs for JavaScript (3382ms)
[18:08:04] <START> Building in-memory fs for Assets
...
```

if the second part was not showing up, you may want to check whether you can use the port:
[image]
With this image you can see the url should be http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true . If you cannot open it in your browser you may need to check your firewall setting or anything else blocking the access.

Also you may want to search index.android.bundle in your native code to check whether the dev url has been modified.

Comment: I think you are right about the script server, however I can't get it run properly no matter what I do.  I run react-native start and the terminal shows no errors when the server start up but I still get the same error.  IOS is not working at all.  I am sure the issue is in my computer but I don't know what could be causing the blockage.  So it looks like I can't use react-native on my machine,  will have to use native script instead which works well but is not as well supported by the community at present.

Comment: So let's check it step by step. Let me edit the answer with more info

Comment: I restarted my mac and tried the android and it now seems to work, even able to make changes and just restart the app and it works fine in the emulator.  Still not able to get anything on the IOS, I just get a blank screen.  LocalHost:8081 does produce a resutls and http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true  finds a very long file so I think the local script server is now working.  I will make sure that I always use a freshly initialised OS and it may be that I was switching localhosts from XAMPP back to reactnative and this may have caused the issue with android

Comment: Thanks for your patience YANG

Comment: how about for iOS version?