# Develop React-native IOS app

Tags: ios, react-native

[image]

when I developed the first app I got error .I'm new to react

please help me to find a solution.
I install npm,node,flow,watchman ,homebrew

Comment: refer to my answer to another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34888831/react-native-init-not-working/34939909#34939909

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your package server isn't running. This should start automatically when you hit run in xcode, but you can also start it manually. From the project's root, run `npm start`

Comment: Thanks for response to post.